# TextInput's onChangeText doesn't get called when Absolute View On Top

Tags: react-native

I'm running into this issue where I have the following UI:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
  <TextInput
    onChangeText={(text) => this.doSearch(text)}/>
  <FlatList />
  <SearchResultList results={this.state.searchResults} />
</View>
```

SearchResultList is as follows:

```
class SearchResultList extends React.PureComponent {

    render() {
        return (
            this.props.results != null ? 
            <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
                <FlatList 
                    data={this.props.results}
                    renderItem={ ({item}) =>
                        <Text>{item.key}</Text>
                    }
                />
            </View>
            :
            null
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    containerStyle: {
        position: 'absolute', 
        top: 155, 
        left: 0, 
        right: 0, 
        bottom: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#FFF'
    }
})
```

When i start typing into the TextInput the application's doSearch gets called appropriately, until the searchresults component displays on screen. As soon as it shows up, onChangeText stops calling doSearch.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong here?

UPDATE: If i change the position of the SearchResultList to 'relative' it works fine...onChangeText starts running doSearch again...I also changed the components to extend from React.Component instead of PureComponent. That didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Extend React.Component rather than React.PureComponent in class SearchResultList, if you need to handle unnecessary renders override:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    return this.props.results !== nextProps.results;
    }
```

Comment: @FelixKhazin What about the main class does it also extends a pure component?

Comment: I changed all the classes to Component just to see if it might help, and it didn't...